# How to reference a python class attribute's type in a function signature

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I have a common problem of referencing a class attribute type in a functions signature. Take for instance:

```py
class Person:
    name: str 

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name 

def greet(name: str):
    return "Hello " + name
```

In the snippet above I'd expect that I could do:

```py
class Person:
    name: str 

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name 

def greet(name: Person.name):
    return "Hello " + name
```

But this gives me an error pyright error `Expected class type but received str`.

I have gotten around it in a couple ways.

1. Define a type and use it in both instances.

```
PersonName = str

class Person:
    name: PersonName 

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name 

def greet(name: PersonName):
    return "Hello " + name
```

2. use `reveal_type`.

```
class Person:
    name: str

    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name 

def greet(name: reveal_type[Person.name]):
    return "Hello " + name
```

This feels like a simple thing to do but I've struggle to find a clean way. What am I missing?

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers so far. I understand python typing doesn't parse `Person.name`. I'm trying to understand if there is any syntax for accessing the type of a class attribute. It appears `reveal_type` works but it feels like there should be a better way? For instance this is how it would be done in typescript.

```js
class Person {
  name: string;
}

function greet(name: Person["name"]) {
  console.log(`hello ${name}`)
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're missing is that it isn't designed to work that way (because the **point** of using "typing" is to check for problems **before the code runs**, whereas the code would have to run first before `Person.name` could mean anything), and that you're intended to use one of those workarounds.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel _"the code would have to run first before Person.name could mean anything"_. I disagree with that. Type checkers _read_ the code in order and can understand the creation of type aliases for example, which can be used further down to annotate variables. (see my answer below) The issue here IMO is not runtime vs. static analysis. The issue is that `Person.name` is just not valid as a type annotation because **it is not a type**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers here are not wrong, but missing the actual point.

It seems to me that you just misunderstand, what it is you are actually doing, when you write `name: Person.name`. The right hand side is **attribute access**, meaning you are accessing the **value** of the `name` attribute of `Person`.

But `Person` is a class and the way you defined it, that class **has no attribute `name`**. It just has an **annotation** for `name`. You can see that if you just try and do the following:

```py
class Person:
    name: str

print(Person.__annotations__)
print(Person.name)
```

The first `print` will give you `{'name': <class 'str'>}`, whereas the second will not even execute because `Person.name` will raise an `AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'name'`.

---

You *could* create that class attribute by assigning a value to `name` in the class namespace:

```py
class Person:
    name: str = "foo"
```

Now `Person.name` actually exists as an attribute.

But that would not solve your problem because that value is a string i.e. an **instance** of the `str` class. Yet you want to annotate a variable with that, specifically you are doing this:

```py
def greet(name: Person.name): ...
```

Which would be equivalent to this:

```py
def greet(name: "foo"): ...
```

While syntactically correct, this makes no sense to any type checker because a variable annotation must be done with a **type**, not an instance. *That* is what pyright is telling you: `Expected class type but received str`. It sees that you are trying to annotate the `name` function parameter with an instance of `str`, but you *should* use an instance of `type` (or a special typing construct such as `Union`).

By the way, the type checker does *not* see what *specific* instance of `str` is used in that annotation because it does not *execute* your code, it just reads it. It does not know (or care) that the value at that point is always `"foo"`. The only thing it sees is that `Person.name` is a `str` instance and that is obviously not valid for type annotations.

---

In your third code snippet you are technically just implicitly creating what is called a **type alias** by assigning `PersonName = str`. Those are also totally fine to use in annotations, which is why there is no problem there. The type checker just resolves both `name: PersonName` annotations (in the `Person` class namespace and in the `greet` function signature) to `name: str` as in your very first snippet.

To drive this point home, starting with Python `3.10` you *could* also do the following:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias


class Person:
    name_type: TypeAlias = str
    name: name_type


def greet(name: Person.name_type) -> None:
    print("Hi", name)
```

Notice again that the `name_type` attribute actually exists after the `Person` class is fully defined. Which means, by the time we get to the function definition, we can use that attribute to annotate the parameter. (Though I find this approach quite ugly.)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Karl Knechtel states in the comment, it is not how typing is designed to work. You are describing an **interface** using typing, so if I import your package/class and try to call a function, I should know how to do so. It makes sense for custom classes you could define (`np.ndarray` or `pd.DataFrame` are all over my code!), but if the interface for interacting with the class field is just `str` you should be using that, and the variable name should tell me the rest. If you have specific additional restrictions for `Person.name` making it not quack like a `str`, it is a separate class. If not, use `str`.

On that note, if what you *really* want is defining a schema with possible additional validation and whatnot, you should look towards something like [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) or [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).